# Can't upload File -- Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, visual-workflow, upload

Hello guys I have a problem with a File upload field of a Flow that is contained in an aura component. I directly show the Aura component in a Page Site, that is why I need the Aura component.
The problem comes when the user tries to upload a file with a permitted extention but I receive the message 'Can't upload file ****'. I check all of the permissions and general settings, sharing settings, permission set, everything, and also checked the other post that have the same problem as me, but I have not find any solution.

I have to mention that with the system admin I do not have any issue. It only happends with the user (this user a Partner Community licence)

Could anybody help me? could the flow embebed inside the Aura component affect? Thanks

Comment: Are there triggers or validation rules on ContentVersion that may be stopping the upload? Do you have multiple ContentVersion record types? How large is the file - if it's too big you might see this error. Where is the file being uploaded to (such as a library)? Does your user [have the Salesforce CRM Content feature enabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)? This is a difficult error to track down because the cause is hidden from the partner community licensed user.

Comment: @nbrown thank you for replying... I do not have any trigger on ContentVersion nor at least one RecordType (I have none RecordType on ContentVersion). The file size is 147KB. I do not know what do you mean by 'Where is the file being uploaded?' I am saving the document in the File and Notes&Attachments related list.

Comment: @nbrown where is exactly the option that allows me to enable my CRM content document?

Comment: If you're saving the file in the related list, that implies you're also creating a ContentDocumentLink to go with the file. Does the partner user have access to the record it's being tied to?

Comment: Are you using LWR? Aura's not compatible with LWR.

Answer (score 1):

So I finally found out what was the problem and it had to to with a permission I had not enabled. In your Profile/Permission set you have to enable Enable Chatter checkbox in System Permission.

Comment: That makes sense [if the file is getting attached to a post or comment](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_attach_parent.htm&type=5) but otherwise seems unnecessary. Is that where the file is getting added?